# Any not-founded command return python error

Tags: command-line, 20.04

Example:

```
~$ ifconfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

or same for any random text:

```
~$ somecommand
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_enable_load_extension
```

Comment: Make a backup of your **/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so** file and copy-paste [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18whyNTrCM8D-DtRl36Y1s9AciStPOzuR/view?usp=sharing). The version is same as yours and that is working fine in my system.

Comment: @Parsa Mousavi that link needs google access.

Comment: Oh my bad . I forgot to make it accessible to anyone. You can download it now.